# Trouble updating local master with upstream repository

Tags: git, github

I feel that I may have bricked things bad enough that I should just nuke everything and redo it, I don't recall what I've done to brick it.

I have a remote repo forked from someone else. I did a pull request from their repo onto my own so that I could update it. (I think this was my mistake.).

I am trying to pull from my remote repo down to my local repo using a method posted on the original's CONTRIBUTING.md, but I have the following problem:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Workspace\Cataclysm-DDA>git pull --ff-only upstream master
From https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I have read to try the following, but it also doesn't work:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Workspace\Cataclysm-DDA>git pull --ff-only upstream master --allow-unrelated-histories
From https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

I believe that I'm having this "fast-forward" problem because I have the following on my github repo: "This branch is 1 commit ahead of CleverRaven:master.", I think this is because I did a pull request onto the DanielPBak fork which added to the history, but I have no clue how to a) undo the pull request and get rid of the commit and b) how to properly sync up.

https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

has the instructions for how to correctly update my fork and local repo, but I feel some small mistakes and attempts to fix those mistakes have bricked my repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you broke this instructions:

> - Keep your master branch clean. This means you can easily pull changes made to this repository into yours.
> - Create a new branch for each new feature or set of related bug fixes.
> - Never merge from your local branches into your  master branch. Only    update that by pulling from upstream/master.

You should rename your local `master`:

```
git checkout master
git branch -M master-old
```

then checkout remote `master`:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/master -b master
```

### EDIT:

To update your broken remote `master` use on local fixed `master`:

```
git push --force [remote] master
```

Comment: I'm still having a problem.  On a different computer, I cloned my remote repo, and I still had this problem, needing to go over these steps all over again. I think this is because, while these steps fixes my local repo, my remote master repo is still messed up and different from the upstream repo. How can I fix this? Or do I just need to deal with doing these steps every time I clone again?

Comment: Since this is giving me so much trouble, I decided to just nuke the entire project. But I would like to know, for future reference, how I could have fixed my forked remote repository master.

Comment: To update your broken remote `master` use on local fixed `master`:

    `git push --force [remote] master`